# At job doesn't stop?

Tags: cron, schedule

I'm trying to schedule a job on Ubuntu using `at` command:

```
/opt$ at now + 1 min
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
  at> echo "test" > /opt/t.txt
  at> <EOT>
```

However, the job doesn't stop after starting. This is a job info from `atq`:

```
20      Tue Jun 21 14:37:00 2016 = someuser
```

'=' indicates that the job is currently running.

Why it doesn't stop?

Comment: Strange, I can't reproduce this anomalous behavior on a 14.04.4 Ubuntu LTS setup.  What do you get from `$ at -V` ? Also try: `$ at now +1min`(LF) `at> echo "$(date)" " - test" > foobar` (LF) `at> CTRL-D` (LF) `$ at -l; more foobar`. What do you get ?

Comment: @Cbhihe Result from `$ at -V` : `at version 3.1.14 Please report bugs...` .

Comment: OK. We have the same version. Now, please, try: `$ at now +1min` (LF) `at> echo "$(date)" " - test" > foobar` (LF) `at> CTRL-D` (LF) `$ at -l; more foobar`. What do you get ?

Comment: @Cbhihe Here is a result: `21      Thu Jun 23 09:37:00 2016 = someuser` \n
`foobar: No such file or directory`

Comment: `foobar` does not exist ???  Sorry, I can't make any sense of this.